# Handling Recursive models in EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

For the life of me, I can not get this to persist (And reload) with EF 6....

```
public class SillyModel
{
    public SillyModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Children = new List<SillyModel>();
    }
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SillyModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: I would think you need to tell it the Foreign Key for Children.  Like ParentId -> Id.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me (although as @Daniel Lorenz points out having a Foreign Key property is a best-practice):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    public class SillyModel
    {
        public SillyModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Children = new List<SillyModel>();
        }
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Value { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SillyModel> Children { get; } = new HashSet<SillyModel>();
    }
    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SillyModel> SillyModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
    }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(true);

                var e = new SillyModel();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    e.Children.Add(new SillyModel());
                }

                db.SillyModels.Add(e);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```